# Remote Tomcat 7 debug issues in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, tomcat, jpda

I'm able to create a simple Web project in Eclipse that has a simple single HelloWorld servlet.  I'm able to debug this fine with the local Tomcat (setting breakpoints in the index.jsp or in the servlet), which land when I try the sample URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/RemoteDebugTest/HelloWorld
```

However, when I try to use the Eclipse debug configuration for a remote java application, I am able to connect and see the server threads, but my application does not deploy, and the URL appears as if the web module never deployed.  (There are 404 errors for the same URL above.)  Help me StackOverflow, you're my only hope.

Things I have tried:

Set environment variables such as JPDA_ADDRESS to 8000, JPDA_TRANSPORT to dt_socket.
Set those in the catalina.sh (on a remote linux Tomcat7 server) or catalina.bat
Run the catalina startup script with jpda run, or with jpda start

I've extensively scoured online resources and noone else seems to have this problem, other than one article that simply recommended Jetty.  (I came from a background of never having a problem with this using WAS.)

Other pieces of info:

OS: Windows 7 (64-bit)
Tomcat 7.0.0.28
MyEclipse 10 (based on Eclipse 3.7.2)

Comment: maybe, its not even jpda related? i mean i could be a deployment problem.

Comment: Not sure if you already resolved this, but one question what do you mean by "I am able to connect and see the server threads, but my application does not deploy, and the URL appears as if the web module never deployed"? Normally what I do is I first deploy the application on tomcat (remote/local) and start it and just try to hit any of the application URL and see if everything is working fine and then only I start my Remote Debugging configuration in eclipse and have one breakpoint in one of the class